# Parse URLs using Regex, Ignoring Code Blocks and Code Snippets in Markdown

Tags: c#, regex, markdown

I am currently using this regular expression in my C# / .NET Core app to parse HTTP, HTTPS & FTP urls from a markdown file:

```cs
static readonly Regex _urlRegex = new Regex(@"(((http|ftp|https):\/\/)+[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;\/~\+#])?)");

void UpdateGitHubReadme(string gitHubRepositoryName, string gitHubReadmeText)
{
    var updatedMarkdown = _urlRegex.Replace(gitHubReadmeText, x => HandleRegex(x.Groups[0].Value, gitHubRepositoryName.Replace(".", "").Replace("-", "").ToLower(), "github", gitHubUser.Alias));

    //handle updated markdown
}

static string HandleRegex(in string url, in string repositoryName, in string channel, in string alias)
{
    //handle url
}
```

I am looking to update this regex to ignore URLs inside of markdown code blocks and markdown code snippets.

#### Example 1

The following URL should be ignored because it is inside of a code block:

` ` `
{
"name": "Brandon",
"blog" : "https://codetraveler.io"
}

` ` `

#### Example 2

The following URL should be ignored because it is inside of a code snippet:

`curl -I https://www.keycdn.com `

Comment: Is the regex used in C#? Are you replacing text?

Comment: Yes, the regex is being used in C#. I'll edit the question to include this. I'm also a regex n00b - if you don't mind me asking - how does C# impact this regex?

Comment: .NET regex has no feature like `(*SKIP)(*F)` in PCRE to skip ("ignore") maches. You need to use code.

Comment: Good to know! I'll add the C# code to the question.

Comment: Do not escape `/`, they are not any special regex metacharacters. Overescaping is not a good practice. `\;` also matches `;`, but there is no reason for that.

Comment: Oh - good to know! I apologize for my edit and assuming it was just a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage your existing code that already has a match evaluator as the replacement argument in `Regex.Replace`.

You need to add an alternative (with `|` alternation operator) to the current regex that would match the contexts where you want to ignore matches, and then check which group matched.

The alternative you should add is `` (?<!`)(`(?:`{2})?)(?:(?!\1).)*?\1 ``, it matches

- `` (?<!`) ``  - no backtick immediately to the left is allowed
- `` (`(?:`{2})?) `` - Group 1: a backtick and then an optional double backtick sequence
- `(?:(?!\1).)*?` - any char other than a line break char, zero or more occurrences but as few as possible, that does not start the same char sequence that is captured in Group 1
- `\1` - the same char sequence that is captured in Group 1

See the sample code:

```
static readonly Regex _urlRegex = new Regex(@"(?<!`)(`(?:`{2})?)(?:(?!\1).)*?\1|((?:ht|f)tps?://[\w-]+(?>\.[\w-]+)+(?:[\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?)", RegexOptions.Singleline);

void UpdateGitHubReadme(string gitHubRepositoryName, string gitHubReadmeText)
{
    var updatedMarkdown = _urlRegex.Replace(gitHubReadmeText, x => x.Groups[2].Success ?
         HandleRegex(x.Groups[0].Value, gitHubRepositoryName.Replace(".", "").Replace("-", "").ToLower(), "github", gitHubUser.Alias) : x.Value);

    //handle updated markdown
}
```

I modified the URL pattern a bit to make it cleaner and more efficient.